# Program wont run to the end after function is called

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop

I wrote a program to accept 15 integer values in an array, then pass this array to a function which will multiply each even index value by 4.

Currently the program displays the initial array, but seems like it's getting hung up before it displays the modified array.

Please help me understand why the program is getting stuck here!

```
    int main(){
    const int SIZE = 15;
    int quad[SIZE] = {};
    void quadruple(int[], const int);

    cout << "Enter 15 integer values into an array." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)                               // Accept 15 int values
    {
        cout << i << ": ";
        cin >> quad[i];
    }

    cout << "Before quadruple function is called: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << quad[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    quadruple(quad, SIZE);
    cout << "After even index value multiplication: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << quad[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void quadruple(int values[], const int SZ){
    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i + 2)                // Multiply even values by 4
    {
        if ((i % 2) == 0)
        {
            values[i] = values[i] * 4;
        }
        else                                      // Keep odd values the same
        {
            values[i] = values[i] * 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i + 2` what would the rubber duck say?

Comment: Someone will get to ask you to use debugger and to engage rubber duck debugging. Why not me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i + 2)
```

"i + 2" doesn't do anything.

You probably meant "i += 2;".

Your homework assignment is to find some documentation about your system's debugger. And find where your rubber duck is, as it's been suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thank you sir, I shall explain each line to my rubber duck.